# Ionic3 - dynamically show many items in a table of equally sized cells

Tags: ionic3

How can I dynamically show e.g. 60 items in a grid / table? The number of columns is fixed, e.g. 6.

Each item is clickable and will call a method with the selected item. Per row there are (e.g.) 6 columns. The size of the table is determined dynamically by the list of retrieved items.

Comment: Get the (available) height of your grid and divide it by the number of items -> Now you have the height of your row... Just make sure you won't create rows with to little size as you might not be able to click them anymore

Comment: OK, what kind of cells: using ion-row etc? Or is there layout like the Android.GridView/Layout?

Comment: Yeah, I'd use the [ionic grid](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/) and dynamically create rows and columns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Phonolog - thank you for showing me the way. I +1 your answer.

To display e.g. 60 items in max 6 columns wide, you can do:

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col *ngFor="let element of elements" col-2>
      {{element}}
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate a grid with dynamically generated rows and columns you could use following code:

```
<ion-grid>
    <!-- Assuming dynamicElements is an Array holding your items -->
    <ion-row *ngFor="let element of dynamicElements">
        <ion-col>
            {{element.name}}
        </ion-col>
        <!-- Your other columns go here -->
        <ion-col>
            <button ion-button>Button text</button>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

I'm using the [Ionic Grid](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/) and a [`*ngFor`-loop](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf). See the docs for further info e.g. on how to size or align your columns.

The grid will take pretty much the size of `dynamicElements.length * rowHeight`

---

I'm not sure if I understood you right, but if you want to dynamically calculate the row's height to fit everything in a given height following pseudo-code should do:

```
rowHeight = gridHeight / dynamicElements.length
```